# In Go gin framework , how to get all url that I have registered in the router

Tags: go, casbin

I’m programming the role based access control with casbin. However ,the police need me to provide urls that the role has. The “v1” column in the table, see the picture.
I wondered can I get all urls that I registered in router. So that I don’t need to add by my hand.

Comment: You're referring to a picture that is absent from your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Routes`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Engine.Routes) which would return slice of [`RoutesInfo`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#RoutesInfo) through which you can get all the register route path plus additional informaiton.

[`RoutesInfo`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#RoutesInfo) will contain below struct from which required information can be retrieved.

```golang
type RouteInfo struct {
    Method      string
    Path        string
    Handler     string
    HandlerFunc HandlerFunc
}
```

```golang
r := gin.Default()
r.Routes()
```

Answer (score 1):

`*gin.Engine.Routes()` does give the endpoints, but is quite weird because it returns another struct which is what actually contain the slice of `RouteInfo`, without the s. `RouteInfos` is what `.Routes()` actually returns.

In my use-case, I wanted to display the endpoints in the `/` endpoint for easy checking. Here's my code for that:

```
ginGine.GET("/", func(ctx *gin.Context) {
    if gin.Mode() == gin.DebugMode {
        ctx.Data(200, "application/json; charset=utf-8", []byte( fmt.Sprintf("%v", ginGine.Routes()) ))
    }
})
```